# Using typedef struct variables as a value of other variables in same typedef struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have a file that I have to read in C, and the file's format is as followed

the first line of the file is an integer, indicating the number of lines in the file after this line

> 3

and then every subsequent line have the format like this

> string integer integer integer integer

so a sample output of the file will be

```
> 3
> string integer integer integer integer
> string integer integer integer integer
> string integer integer integer integer
```

Now I want to make a **typedef struct** and save the value of first-line into variable int numberoflines inside typedef struct and string value in char* string[numberofline] and integer value in int* value1, int* value2, int* value3, int* value4

so my code  looks something like this

```
typedef struct{
// no of lines
int numberOfLine;//<-:
                   //|
// class details  // |
char* name[numberOfLine]; // i know this is wrong please read further
    int* age;
    int* class;
    int* mathPercentage;
    int* sciencePercentage;
}classDetail;
```

Now many of you must have noticed the problem, and that is

> ```
> // this is wrong and it's a syntax error
> char* name[numberOfLine];
> ```

I cannot use variable numberOfLine here. But I don't know what else to do.

Because the number of lines in the file is not fixed and I am making a 2D char array in C, to store all strings of the file into that 2D array. So If there are 3 lines in the file I have to store 3 strings and if there are 5 lines in the file I need to store 5 strings. That means I cannot use a random number.

I also thought about using a double-pointer,

```
char**name;
```

But I was not able to allocate memory to it properly or maybe I do not know how to allocate memory properly to a char**.

Now I don't have any idea how to tackle this Issue and I request you to please help me out.

Comment: `classDetail.name = malloc(classDetail.numberOfLine * sizeof(char *))`

Comment: If you want to know the size of the array at compile time but the size will not be known until runtime, then the problem is not one of language syntax.  Rather, it is a temporal paradox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an *array* of structs.

In the `struct`, most fields are simple `int` variables.

Only `name` need be either a `char` array or `char *` pointer

After reading the line that has the record count (e.g. `numberOfLine`), you can do a single `malloc` to allocate the array

Here's some [incomplete] code to illustrate the basic structure:

```
#define MAXNAME     100
typedef struct {
    int age;
    int class;
    int mathPercentage;
    int sciencePercentage;
    char name[MAXNAME];
} classDetail1;
classDetail1 *class1;

typedef struct {
    int age;
    int class;
    int mathPercentage;
    int sciencePercentage;
    char *name;
} classDetail2;
classDetail2 *class2;

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[1000];

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
    int numberOfLine = atoi(buf);

    class1 = malloc(sizeof(*class1) * numberOfLine);

    // read in all lines ...
    int lineidx = 0;
    while (1) {
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // point to record for current line
        classDetail1 *cur = &class1[lineidx];

        // parse the line and save into struct ...

        ++lineidx;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want a construct that can hold an array of values of some complex type, and the array should be dynamically sized.

First, let's cover the lines, since they are our "records":

```
struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int class;
    int mathPercentage;
    int sciencePercentage;
} typedef Record;
```

Then, a dynamically sized array of those:

```
struct {
    int count;
    Record *rows;
} typedef Records;
```

We'd create and destroy such an object as follows:

```
Records *newRecords(int count) {
  Records *records = malloc(sizeof(Records));
  if (!records) abort();
  records->count = count;
  records->rows = calloc(count, sizeof(Record)); // like malloc, but zeroes the memory
  if (!records->rows) abort();
  return records;
}

void freeRecordContents(Record *record) {
  if (record) free(record->name);
}

// it's OK to call this with a null pointer
// just as it is OK to call free() with a null pointer
void freeRecords(Records *records) {
  if (records && records->rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < records->count; ++i)
      freeRecordContents(&(records->rows[i]));
  if (records) free(records->rows);
  free(records);
}
```

Then, to set the individual values in the rows, you'd use normal array indexing:

```
int count;
fscanf(file, "%d", &count);
Records *records = newRecords(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  Record *row = &(records->rows[i]);  // <- rows[i] is used to access one row
  char tmpName[512];
  fscanf("%511s %d %d %d %d ", &tmpName, 
         &(row->age), &(row->class),
         &(row->mathPercentage), &(row->sciencePercentage));
  row->name = strdup(tmpName);
  if (!row->name) abort();
}
```

Note how `fscanf`'s format string ends with a space: that's so that it'll "consume" any whitespace, newlines, etc., to make everything ready for reading the next line.

Now, `strdup` is a POSIX thing, not a part of standard C, so to make our program portable, we need to define our own `strdup`:

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {
  size_t len = strlen(src) + 1;
  char *dst = malloc(len);
  if (dst) memcpy(dst, src, len);
  return dst;
}
```

You may have noticed that to allocate `Records` we need to allocate at least twice: first the `Records` structure, then the `rows` array. Both of those allocations can be combined - not a big deal for a homework assignment like yours, but in production code it helps with performance by keeping the `Records` structure and the `rows` together in memory.

We'd only need to modify the `Records` structure and the allocation/deallocation functions. The indexing of `rows` would still work the same way. And thus:

```
struct {
     int count;
     Record rows[1]; // this array really has a dynamic size, not fixed at 1
} typedef Records;

Records *newRecords(int count) {
  // count-1 because Records already has room for one Records
  size_t size = sizeof(Records) + (count-1) * sizeof(Record);
  Records *records = calloc(size, 1);
  if (!records) abort;
  records->count = count;
  return records;
}

void freeRecords(Records *records) {
  if (records)
    for (int i = 0; i < records->count; ++i)
      freeRecordContents(&(records->rows[i]));
  free(records);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I am not able to understand this part of the char tmpName[512]; I think this tmpName has some bug because it stores the first character for some reason. let's say if a child name abc is there so tmpName will copy a of abc then let's say a kid named xyz is in the list after abc then tmpName will add a of abc to xyz and will make it axyz and let's say there is another child pqr after xyz now tmpName will add ax to pqr and will make it axpqr. So I think there is some bug there